# Name of the content-type of XML-like data

Tags: xml, mime-types, terminology, file-format

Is there a generic term for *hierarchical text data with attributes* stored in an XML file? Like `bmp` and `png` and `jfif` files contains *raster graphics*, `wav`, `mp3` and `ogg` files contains *sound*, `smf` contains *music performance data* etc. XML-like data can be serialised in different ways. For example, end tags can be written by closing parenthesis, one can use escape characters instead of entities/CDATA sections. It can also be a Matroska, which is some binary encoding of similar structures. The XML files are called "application/xml
text/xml" so it is an example of an "Application" file, but any file is an "Application" file.

---

What about *Text resource data*? It is generic and probably enlightens the main purpose.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're counting as "XML-like" other than XML - for which the name would seem to be "XML data". For that matter, you could use XML to store a raster image if you wanted - and frequently do use it to store vector images (e.g. SVG) - so that comparison doesn't shed much light on what you're after...

Comment: @IMSoP You store anything in any file format. If you by storing raster image in XML mean using base-64 encoding, the encoded data is not XML data. A raster image stored properly in XML would need one element per color channel value `<pixel><red>64</red><green>128</green><blue>256</blue></pixel>`. Yes you can do it, but it is far from optimal.

Comment: I didn't say it was *likely*, just that there isn't really an answer to "TIFF is to raster graphics as XML is to _", because they're such different levels of abstraction. You could clearly say "TIFF is to raster graphics as SVG is to vector graphics", but SVG happens to be stored as hierarchical XML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose the term `TextResource`, since it is what it should be used for within the project scope: Documents, Configuration files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a very flexible, and very low-level, format, so it's hard to describe its "data type" outside of a concrete usage.

For instance, in different contexts, you could describe XML data as (these aren't mutually exclusive):

- marked up text, per the "M" in XML; e.g. XHTML, DocBook
- serialized application data; e.g in SOAP or RESTful web services
- metadata describing another resource; e.g. RSS/Atom feeds, project manifests and configuration files
- hierarchical object data; e.g. SVG
- self-referential data definitions; e.g. XML Schema

Or you could define it by the *purpose* of the data - if a JPEG file is a "raster image", then an SVG file is a "vector image", a DocBook file is a "documentation file", etc - with XML simply being a detail of the format used, just as "sequence of big-endian 16-bit words" would be.